# How can I make appear element by element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if I wrote something wrong :(

I get success with this, but if I'd have a lot of paragraphs to show one by one?

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#click").click(
            function() {
                $("body").append("<p class='add'>joaoao</p>");
                $("p.add").fadeIn("slow", function(){
                    $("body").append("<p class='add'>joaoao</p>");
                    $("p.add").fadeIn();
                });

            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: Use a for loop, it's the go to loop of JS. `for(va i=0; i < ar.length; i++) {}`

Comment: Can you explain a bit more detail? Will you have an object with loads of paragraph texts in it and render one "click" element for each paragraph?

Comment: So tell me exactly what you want... how many paragraphs to append? In what time-frame? Etc.

Comment: If I use the for loop all the elements appear in just one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would refactor the code a bit so that all the paragraphs already exist in the HTML. Then, just show them one by one -- each time, show the first one that's still hidden. I give the function a name to call it recursively as the callback.

```
        $("#click").click(
            function fadeIn() {
                $("p:hidden").first().fadeIn("slow", fadeIn);

            }
        );
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/Lakcxduc/)

Comment: For some reason it didn't work in the Stack Snippet but it does in the fiddle link i put up. Must be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can write simple sequencer:

```js
function startSequence(selector) {
  var idx = 0;
  var seq = $(selector);

  var id = window.setInterval( function() { 
     if( idx >= seq.length ) {
       window.clearInterval(id);
       return;
     }
     $(seq[idx]).addClass("shown");
     ++idx;
   }, 1000 );
}

startSequence("p");
```

```css
p { color:transparent; background-color:transparent; }
p.shown { color:#000; background-color:gold; transition: all linear 1s; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>1111111111111111</p>
<p>2222222222222222</p>
<p>33333333333333</p>
<p>344444444444444</p>
<p>5555555555</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got success with this example:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#click").click(
            function() {

                var count = prompt("How many joao's do you want to appear?");
                var int = setInterval(
                    function(){
                        if(count==1){
                            clearInterval(int);
                        }
                        $("body").append("<p class='add'>joaoao</p>");
                        $(".add").fadeIn();
                        count--;
                    }
                    ,800);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

following p tag only appears after the last stop animation.
thanks for the help guys!!!